ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 HttpRequest ToGenericHttpRequest() extension not handling request body
I'm creating an endpoint to support IDP initiated SAML SSO and the request from the client has a body that's a base64 encoded XML which looks like this:
SAMLResponse:PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGl...

However when I call Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(validate: true) it fails on this line because the request is obviously not a form, samlHttpRequest.Form = ToNameValueCollection(request.Form);.
Is the SAML assertion being sent to me not standard in the way it's a base64 encoded string prefixed with SAMLResponse? It seems like it is which suggests I'm trying to ingest and validate the SAMLResponse the wrong way...

It is not a standard SAML 2.0 response I'm afraid and not supported by the library. Maybe you can load the response into the classes your self. But it is not something I have tried before.

Ok, thank you. I'll see what I can do.
